# System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7fe4a73e70 (key_handle 0x9526436)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Application crash, no errors in code. Something confuses to think that there is C# and Java mixed maybe? Im using Visual Studio Code and Xamarin Forms

here´s my code:

```
GoogleSignInClient.cs
using Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn;

namespace passikaveriApp.Droid
{
    internal class GoogleSignInClient
    {
        public object SignInIntent { get; internal set; }

        public static implicit operator GoogleSignInClient(GoogleSignInClientWrapper v)
        {
            return new GoogleSignInClient
            {
                SignInIntent = v.SignInIntent
            };
        }

        public static implicit operator GoogleSignInClient(Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn.GoogleSignInClient v) => new GoogleSignInClient
        {
            SignInIntent = v.SignInIntent
        };
    }

    internal class GoogleSignInClientWrapper
    {
        public GoogleSignInClientWrapper(GoogleSignInClient client)
        {
            SignInIntent = client.SignInIntent;
        }

        public object SignInIntent { get; }
    }
}
```

```
and here is my MainActivity.cs:
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace passikaveriApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IOnCompleteListener
    {
        // GoogleSignInClient olio
        readonly GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
        const int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

        public MainActivity()
        {
            // alustetaan GoogleSignInOptions
            var gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                .RequestIdToken(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.default_web_client_id))
                .RequestEmail()
                .Build();

            // alustetaan GoogleSignInClient
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.GetClient(this, gso);
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);

            // Lisätään "Kirjaudu Google tilillä"-nappi
            var button = new Xamarin.Forms.Button { Text = "Kirjaudu Google tilillä" };
            button.Clicked += OnGoogleSignInButtonClicked;


            var stackLayout = new StackLayout { Children = { button } };
            App.Current.MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = stackLayout };
        }

        // Käsitellään clicked toiminta
        async void  OnGoogleSignInButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // käynnistetään Google sign-in olio
            var signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.SignInIntent;
            StartActivityForResult((Intent)signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }

        private void StartActivityForResult(object signInIntent, int rC_SIGN_IN)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        // Käsitellään olion tulokset
        public async void OnComplete(Task task)
        {
            try
            {
                // Otetaan kirjautunut tili
                var result = await GoogleSignIn.GetSignedInAccountFromIntentAsync((Intent)task.Result);

                // käytetään tiliä kirjautumiseen
                // ...

                // Näytetään viesti käyttäjälle
                Toast.MakeText(this, $"Welcome, {result.DisplayName}!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                //kirjautuminen epäonnistui
                Toast.MakeText(this, $"Sign-in failed: {e.StatusMessage}", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
            {
                var task = GoogleSignIn.GetSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                var listener = new OnCompleteListener(this);
                listener.CompleteTask += OnComplete;
                task.AddOnCompleteListener(listener);
            }
        }
            internal class OnCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
        {
            private readonly MainActivity mActivity;

            public OnCompleteListener(MainActivity activity)
            {
                mActivity = activity;
            }

            public event Action<Task> CompleteTask;

            public void OnComplete(Task task)
            {
                mActivity.OnComplete(task);
            }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Try running the app, and use google sign in, but it crash before button show up.
Any idea what may confuse it to think using Java? Or is there something I misundestood :D
Any help would be nice!

Comment: oh, and here is the full error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7fe4a73e70 (key_handle 0x9526436) of Java type 'crc649d358d7534b1ffbd/MainActivity' as managed type 'passikaveriApp.Droid.MainActivity'.'

Comment: The error messages says "MANAGED".  c# is managed and you are attempting to call a method that is not managed (usually c++ application).  Most likely you have to use Marshal methods and DLLImpoxrt to call api.  The error message may not be precise.  You could be accessing memory that is not assigned to the app and getting a memory access error and error is assuming the code is not managed.